# mysql not install into vendor/bundle

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bundler

I am trying to get mysql rebuilt and installed into vendor/bundle.

ruby version: 1.8.7
rails version: 2.3.8
bundler version: 1.1.3

Gemfile:

```
source "http://rubygems.org"
gem 'rake', '0.8.7'
gem 'fastercsv', '1.5.3'
gem 'rails', '2.3.8'
gem 'mysql', '2.8.1'
...
```

No combination of the following works.  There is no mysql under vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems

```
bundle install
bundle install --path vendor/bundle
bundle package
bundle install --deployment --path vendor/bundle --without test development
```

I expect after the last command it would install mysql into vendor/bundle, maybe if I had the right command before calling bundle install --deployment.

It does install vendor/cache/mysql-2.8.1.gem.

Comment: Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 5.4 (Tikanga) [x86_64]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved my own problem (actually a colleague).

I had tried to get bundler to re-install mysql.  Running bundle did not update the gems under vendor/bundle.  So I deleted the gem.

```
rm -rf vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/mysql-2.8.1
```

However, there were still other mysql files.  When we removed them too, then bundler re-installed mysql.

```
rm vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/specifications/mysql-2.8.1.gemspec
rm vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/cache/mysql-2.8.1.gem
rm vendor/cache/mysql-2.8.1.gem
```